# What happens when I convert to Delphi AES256 and the value is wrong?

Tags: delphi

I'm sorry that I posted too many questions on the same topic.
I've been searching Google all day to solve this alone, but I couldn't solve it with my own ability. I am thinking about it, and I am posting the last question.

```
====Other Developer Settings====
Encryption key value: 1q2w3e4r
AES encryption settings)
Cipher mode: CBC
Key size = 16 bytes
Block size = 16 bytes
Ding pk : PKCS7
```

the right value
???????->
AES256-CBC-PKCS7 Value: gRI2SaW/HMknK/5tuJ2S9Q==

My value
???????->
AES256-CBC-PKCS7 Value: A8MAUAUIDpQcNEKNFqZDA==

I don't know why it's different when the results come up as above. The number of characters is the same, but the encrypted value is incorrect and cannot be approved.
AES256 encryption is successful, but what is wrong? ToT

```pascal
function EncryptData(Data: string; AKey: AnsiString; AIv: AnsiString): string;
var
  cipher: TDCP_rijndael;
  key, iv, src, dest, b64: TBytes;
  index, slen, bsize, pad: integer;
begin
  //key := Base64DecodeBytes(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AKey));
  //iv := Base64DecodeBytes(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AIv));
  key := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('1q2w3e4r1q2w3e4r1q2w3e4r1q2w3e4r');
  iv := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('1q2w3e4r1q2w3e4r');

  src := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data);

  cipher := TDCP_rijndael.Create(nil);
  try
    cipher.CipherMode := cmCBC;
    // Add padding.
    // Resize the Value array to make it a multiple of the block length.
    // If it's already an exact multiple then add a full block of padding.
    slen := Length(src);
    bsize := (cipher.BlockSize div 8);
    pad := bsize - (slen mod bsize);
    Inc(slen, pad);
    SetLength(src, slen);
    for index := pad downto 1 do
    begin
      src[slen - index] := pad;
    end;

    SetLength(dest, slen);
    cipher.Init(key[0], 256, @iv[0]); // DCP uses key size in BITS not BYTES
    cipher.Encrypt(src[0], dest[0], slen);

    b64 := Base64EncodeBytes(dest);
    result := TEncoding.Default.GetString(b64);
  finally
    cipher.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```pascal
function Base64EncodeBytes(Input: TBytes): TBytes;
var
  ilen: integer;
begin
  ilen := Length(Input);
  SetLength(result, ((ilen + 2) div 3) * 4);
  Base64Encode(@Input[0], @result[0], ilen);
end;
```

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button9Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Edit2.Text := EncryptData(EditCarNumber.Text,'','');
 end;
```

Comment: Are you sure you are doing it wrong?  I entered your values here https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption and got A8MAUAuIDpQcNEKNnFqZDA==

Comment: @DavidA
Thank you for leaving a comment.
I thought it was good because it was the same as the value from the site, but it was different from the value requested by the site.
So I thought about it for a long time, and I solved it with my senior developer Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it with my senior developer.

If anyone is looking for it, I hope it helps.
Please refer to the question for setting

```pascal
function EncryptData(Data: string; AKey: AnsiString; AIv: AnsiString): string;
var
  cipher: TDCP_rijndael;
  key, iv, src, dest, b64: TBytes;
  index, slen, bsize, pad: integer;
begin
  key := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('1q2w3e4r');       //Specify key value
  iv := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('1q2w3e4r');        //Specify iv value

  SetLength(key, 16);                               //Set the key value to 16 bytes
  SetLength(iv, 16);                                //Set the iv value to 16 bytes

  src := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data);

  cipher := TDCP_rijndael.Create(nil);
  try
    cipher.CipherMode := cmCBC;
    slen := Length(src);
    bsize := (cipher.BlockSize div 8);             //The block size is 8byte

    pad := bsize - (slen mod bsize);
    Inc(slen, pad);
    SetLength(src, slen);
    for index := pad downto 1 do
    begin
      src[slen - index] := pad;
    end;

    SetLength(dest, slen);
    cipher.Init(key[0], 128, @iv[0]);             //key[0], 128bit, @iv[0]take as
    cipher.Encrypt(src[0], dest[0], slen);

    b64 := Base64EncodeBytes(dest);              //Encoding received values to Base64 values
    result := TEncoding.Default.GetString(b64);  //Get b64 value by string.
  finally
    cipher.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why not setting `key` and `iv` to `'1q2w3e4r'#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0` right away? Increasing the length without defining the new bytes is risky.

Comment: @AmigoJack  Thank you for your advice.
I'll apply that to the actual project.
I think it's set like this because it's a practice project.